# How do I list virsh networks without sudo?

Tags: permissions, sudo, virsh

I noticed a strange behavior on one machine using Debian that I can't reproduce on another machine running Ubuntu. When listing `virsh` networks as an ordinary user, it shows an empty list:

```
~$ virsh net-list --all
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
```

When running the same command with `sudo`, it shows the default connection:

```
~$ sudo virsh net-list --all
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 default              active     no            yes
```

The permissions on the files themselves seem to be set correctly:

```
~$ ls -l /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  1 18:19 autostart
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  228 Jul  1 18:19 default.xml
```

The user belongs to `kvm` and `libvirtd` groups.

What is happening? Why can't I list the networks as an ordinary user?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[It appears that](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2011-April/msg00091.html):

> If not explicitly stated, the virsh binary uses the 'qemu:///session' URI
>   (at least under debian).

Therefore, not only `virsh net-list`, but practically any command, including `virsh list`, behaved differently when running with `sudo`. In other words, `virsh net-list` was using user's scope instead of global ones.

This makes sense; trying to create the default connection and then starting it led to “Network is already in use by interface virbr0” error—without knowing it, I was starting a *second* connection named “default”, while one was already running.

The solution is straightforward:

```
virsh --connect qemu:///system net-list
```

does what I was expecting it to do, while:

```
virsh net-list
```

doesn't.

**Why is Ubuntu machine not having the issue?**

According to [the documentation](https://libvirt.org/uri.html#URI_default):

> If virsh finds the environment variable `VIRSH_DEFAULT_CONNECT_URI` set, it will try this URI by default. Use of this environment variable is, however, deprecated now that libvirt supports `LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI` itself.

It appears, indeed, that on Ubuntu machine, the second variable was defined:

```
ubuntu:~$ echo $VIRSH_DEFAULT_CONNECT_URI

ubuntu:~$ echo $LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI
qemu:///system
```

On Debian machine, on the other hand, none of those variables are set:

```
debian:~$ echo $VIRSH_DEFAULT_CONNECT_URI

debian:~$ echo $LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI
```

Setting one of those variables to `qemu:///system` would probably work, but, well, it's easier to specify the connection string directly in `virsh` command (at least when writing a script).

Comment: If you are using ssh it's a very good idea to use "--connect qemu:///system".

Comment: I had the same problem on Rocky Linux 8.5.  `export LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI=qemu:///system` made `virsh list --all` do the right thing without `sudo` for a user in the `libvirt` group.

Answer (score 17):

uncomment this line in file /etc/libvirt/libvirt.conf

```
uri_default = "qemu:///system"
```

was enough for me in fedora 29 .

**Edit:** as it says here https://libvirt.org/uri.html for non root users that file also needs to be in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/libvirt/libvirt.conf

which in my case is:

```
 ~/.config/libvirt/libvirt.conf
```

so i copy the file there (on my fresh install) and now virsh net-list works as a non-root user and no need to espicify --connect

Comment: "also needs" looks as if I need to edit both files. I only created `~/.config/libvirt/libvirt.conf` and did not edit `/etc/libvirt/libvirt.conf`, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to setup virsh to work with local user. More information is here:

https://major.io/2015/04/11/run-virsh-and-access-libvirt-as-a-regular-user/

basically you need to setup polkit rule and connect to libvirtd daemon

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, `root` is (mostly) required, and `virsh` is chatting up a daemon (and not poking around manually at files in the `/etc/libvirt` directory, which a `strace` or `sysdig` will confirm):

```
   Most virsh operations rely upon the libvirt library being able to
   connect to an already running libvirtd service.  This can usually be
   done using the command service libvirtd start.

   Most virsh commands require root privileges to run due to the
   communications channels used to talk to the hypervisor.  Running as non
   root will return an error.
```

So why `virsh list` does not return an error might either be a bug or in need of clarification in the `virsh(1)` man page...